# How to append data to a JSON value of type array in swift 4

Tags: json, swift4, swifty-json, algorithmia

This is my code of the json object. I'm trying to get an image dictionary into the images value. I've tried a lot of things and maybe I'm missing something.

```
 let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
        "name_space": "users",
        "data_collection": "data://brownfosman5000/DatFace/",
        "action" : "add_images",
        "images": []
    ]
```

I have created a json dictionary to hold the images

```
let imageDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: imageJSON, options: []) as! [String : Any]
```

I have also created an array to hold the array of imageDictionaries

```
let images:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
self.images.add(imageDictionary)
```

How can I add the images array to the array in my json as a dictionary?
Everything prints out nice I just need to add it to the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all never use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. Use a native type with the `var` keyword

```
var images = [[String:Any]]()
```

Second of all make `jsonObject` also mutable

```
var jsonObject: [String: Any] = [ ...
```

Append the dictionary to `images`

```
images.append(imageDictionary)
```

Assign the array to the dictionary for key `images`

```
jsonObject["images"] = images
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me to send data to my api!